# Questions written in Japanese should not be blocked by the "quality" filter

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

You cannot write a question in all Japanese because the software does some kind of quality checking. I'm wondering if it is possible fix the quality standards filter to allow questions be posted in Japanese?

For the sake of illustration I'm gonna post an example question (Taken from Chiebukuro):
Title

> ”一目置かれる”とはどういう意味ですか？

Content

> 「なんちゃらかんちゃら」の語源は？
>
> 最近よく「なんちゃらかんちゃら」って聞くような気がします。
>
> 何かの名称で長いもののとき、後半部分を略す場合に、
>   『行列のできるなんちゃらかんちゃら』とか使うような気がします。
>
> もとは、どこかの方言なのでしょうか？ どういった意味なのでしょうか？
>   お詳しい方、教えてください。

This is a perfect valid question in Japanese but the system blocks filters this kind of questions.

Comment: Do you have an example question that was denied by the quality checker that you could post?  I'm sure that it would aid the moderators as an example of what you weren't exactly able to do.

Comment: You should bring this up over on meta.stackoverflow.com as this would ultimately be a Stack Exchange system change that would be needed.

Comment: @RobZ, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232

Comment: @rob this is definitely a site-specific issue; this is as *site-specific* as it gets!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This quality check is definitely tuned for English, or at least [romance languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages).

I have made it a site-level setting and turned it off for this site.

Comment: That was fast! I never even realized there was such a filter.

Comment: That _is_ fast. It would be interesting to know what process was behind that. Was the change QA'd? It kinda blows my mind that you configified a value on a production site and rolled out to production so quick, then again you guys did write the Joel test.

Comment: Writing a Japanese-parsing quality checker would likely be very difficult, but I reckon anyone posting questions in Japanese will probably have a head start on knowing what's appropriate.